# How to navigate cells using TAB key in dgrid

Tags: dgrid

I am trying to enable cell navigation in dgrid using TAB key. (get the same behaviour as with the right arrow key). I have gotten as far as using the keyMap property as explained [in the docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/dev-0.4/doc/components/mixins/Keyboard.md). How do I move focus to the next cell now ?

```js
keyMap: lang.mixin({}, Keyboard.defaultKeyMap, {
  9: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Keyboard.moveFocusRight(event);
  }
})
```

Is this right way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it working this way as explained [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/267)

```js
grid.addKeyHandler(keys.TAB, Keyboard.moveFocusRight);
```